# With jQuery Mobile how can I detect every time a user is viewing a data-role="page"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to fire a function eachtime a data-role page has been displayed.

the page being:

```
<div data-role="page" id="my-page">
```

I can get the alert to fire the first time the page is loaded by using:

```
$('#my-page').on('pageinit', function() { 
    alert('test');
});
```

But I want the alert everytime a user goes to #my-page.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `pageshow` event.
Here is the [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) to the docs.

```
$('#my-page').on('pageshow', function() { 
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pageshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) event like this:

```
$('#my-page').on('pageshow', function() { 
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: That camelCase on pageShow doesn't work, but thanks. +1 for answering first but apfunk has to get the correct answer cos technically your answer doesn't work :)

Comment: @Aaron oops, typo trying to answer quickly. Fixed.